$f(x,y) = 6x y^{2} - 2x^{3} - 3y^{4}$ find and determine the critical points
$f(x,y) = 6x y^{2} - 2x^{3} - 3y^{4}$
find and determine the critical points
in order to find to solve this question I calculated the gradient  and managed to find that $(0,0), (1,1)$ and $(1,-1)$ are critical points, then I calculated the Hessian and managed  to show that $(1,1)$ and $(1,-1)$ are maximum points since their characteristic polynomials are the same and they have $2$ negative eigen values, my problem is only with $(0,0)$ its Hessian is just the zero matrix so I can't do anything about it, what can I do in order to determine it?
They told us to plot the graph and I plotted in Geogebra and found out that it should be a saddle point and they even told us that this is called a "monkey saddle".
Much help will be appreciated!

You have to see what happens in a neighbourhood of $(0,0)$

You are correct. $(0,0)$ is just a saddle point.
For example,
$$
-0.0043=\mathbf{f(-0.1,0.1)<f(0,0)}=0\mathbf{<f(0.1,0.1)}=0.0037.
$$


But how can I prove that rigoursly?

The argument above shows that $(0,0)$ is neither a local maximum nor a local minimum, and in combination with your computed derivatives, that's enough. See Wikipedia definition of the saddle point: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saddle_point

$$f(x,y)=6xy^{2}-2x^{3}-3y^{4}$$
Now $$f_x=6y^{2}-6x^{2}$$
And $$f_y=12xy-12y^{3}$$
Now let's equate the conditions $f_x=0$ and $f_y=0$.
That is $$6(y^{2}-x^{2})=0$$
And $$12y(x-y^{2})=0$$
Therefore $y^{2}-x^{2}=0$ and $y(x-y^{2})=0$
$\implies (y-x)(y+x)=0$ and $y(x-y^{2})=0$
$\implies$ $$(y-x)=0,(y+x)=0$$ and $$y=0,x=y^{2}$$
Therefore the equations are :
$y=0$ ....(i)
$y=x$ ....(ii)
$y=-x$ ....(iii)
$x=y^{2}$ ....(iv)
Therefore the critical points are $$(0,0);(1,1);(1,-1)$$
Now find $f_{xx}, f_{xy}, f_{yy}$
$f_{xx}=-12x=A$
$f_{xy}=12y=B$
$f_{yy}=12x-36y^{2}=C$
Therefore the points $(1,1)$ and $(1,-1)$ are the points of maximum.
Because $AC-B^{2}$ is positive and $A<0$ for both the points $(1,1)$ and $(1,-1)$.
And $AC-B^{2}=0$ is a doubtful case.
But since $f_{xx}=0$ for $(0,0)$, so $(0,0)$ is a saddle point.

but second derivative equals to 0 does not mean it must be a saddle point, for example f(x,y)=x^4+y^4, clearly  the second derivative of this at (0,0) is 0 but (0,0) is a minimum point.

Yes. Actually it is my mistake only. But this $(0,0)$ point is a mystery.
